# No puedo borrar un archivo con "File(string).delete()"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, local-storage

Estoy teniendo un problema con borrar una lista de archivos de audio almacenados en el dispositivo, en concreto, la ruta de los archivos son: content://media/external/audio/media/"identificador del archivo de audio"

ejemplo: content://media/external/audio/media/49411

Y lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma:

```
    private fun deleteSongs(){
        var result = true
        selectedSongsList.forEach(){
           if(!File(it.contentUri).delete()) result = false
        }

        if (!result) Toast.makeText(context, "Una o varias canciones no se han podido eliminar...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        deselectAllCards()
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Como se puede ver en el codigo, si la funcion delete() devuelve false, muestro un toast diciendo que no se ha podido borrar. La funcion siempre me devuelve false, no borra el archivo. Por que ocurre esto? llevo horas con esta tontería sencilla y no consigo encontrar el error.

¿esta mal la ruta del archivo?

Comment: Preguntas si esta mal la ruta, pero de donde o como obtienes la URI ?

Comment: Ya te expliqué esto antes, las **content** uris se trabajan con un **content**Resolver. Esta uri **content**://media/external/audio/media/49411 no se puede convertir a `File`